# parsing packet to get application layer protocols such as http and tls using the dpdk packet framework without being computationally expensive

Tags: c++, packet, dpdk

I have the following packet inspection function that parses transport layer protocols such as TCP and UDP. I need to get deeper into the packet and get application layer protocols such as HTTP and TLS. My current theory is to implement a pattern matching function on the payload but that would be computationally expensive. Any leads on how to proceed?

```
void inspect_packet(struct rte_mbuf *pkt, unsigned port_id, int i)
{
    uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *)(pkt->buf_addr + pkt->data_off);
    unsigned int offset = 0;
    struct rte_ether_hdr *eth = (struct rte_ether_hdr *)data;
    offset += sizeof(struct rte_ether_hdr);

    a_counter[i].pkts_counter++;
    a_counter[i].bits_counter += pkt->pkt_len;

    if (eth->ether_type != htons(RTE_ETHER_TYPE_IPV4) && eth->ether_type != htons(RTE_ETHER_TYPE_IPV6) 
        && eth->ether_type != htons(RTE_ETHER_TYPE_ARP))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (eth->ether_type == RTE_ETHER_TYPE_ARP)
    {
        a_counter[i].arp_counter++;
        return;
    }

    struct rte_ipv4_hdr *iph = (struct rte_ipv4_hdr *)(data + offset);
    struct rte_ipv6_hdr *iph6 = (struct rte_ipv6_hdr *)(data + offset);

    struct rte_tcp_hdr *tcph = NULL;
    struct rte_udp_hdr *udph = NULL;

    if(eth->ether_type == htons(RTE_ETHER_TYPE_IPV4))
    {
        offset += 20; //header length
        switch (iph->next_proto_id)
        {
            case PROTOCOL_TCP:
                a_counter[i].tcp_counter++;
                tcph = (struct rte_tcp_hdr *)(data + offset);
                break;
            
            case PROTOCOL_UDP:
                a_counter[i].udp_counter++;
                udph = (struct rte_udp_hdr *)(data + offset);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else if (eth->ether_type ==  htons(RTE_ETHER_TYPE_IPV6))
    {
        offset += 40; //header length
        switch (iph6->proto)
        {
            case PROTOCOL_TCP:
                tcph = (struct rte_tcp_hdr *)(data + offset);
                break;
            
            case PROTOCOL_UDP:
                udph = (struct rte_udp_hdr *)(data + offset);
                break;
        }
    }
    
    data = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at what tools like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) do (it's open source, so you can inspect the code and it also has world class protocol analysis) ?

Comment: @JesperJuhl the reason why i have chosen dpdk is because i want to achieve traffic analysis at line speeds (upto 10gbps), something which isn't possible with wireshark

Comment: That doesn't mean you cannot use it for inspiration/ideas.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta based on the question explanation `My current theory is to implement a pattern matching function on the payload but that would be computationally expensive. Any leads on how to proceed?` . So first please update the title `reflecting the intent`. With respect to pattern matching one can use `regex` like `hyperscan library from intel`. There is also regex PMD in the 22.02 DPDK.

Comment: @VipinVarghese that theory is more like a "best guess on how to proceed". I'll update the title if you believe pattern matching is the best way to go about this question. Please acknowledge if it is.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta I did not follow your last comment, is you real requirement `need help in sample reference code for using packet parsing using DPDK libraries`. If yes, please update the title. Else I did not follow your question `can you explain what  is that you are looking for`. By the way, I have already made use of hyperscan to parse and compare-match packet | payload content while using DPDK. So the earlier comment shared is not a `best guess`.

Comment: @VipinVarghese what i am looking for is a way to get application layer data (whether the packet belongs to HTTP, HTTPS, QUIC etc). Getting transport layer data is easy via the headers (rte_tcp_hdr and rte_udp_hdr). But i need to access the payload in order to get the application layer data. We can discuss this in depth via mail if it works for you. I can share my current working code for better articulation of my problem. I'll post my conclusion here once i reach a solution.

Comment: @VipinVarghese can you share example code on how to implement hyperscan?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta I can make myself available now, google meet, skype zoom works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[based on the live discussion]

Question: My current theory is to implement a pattern-matching function on the payload but that would be computationally expensive. Any leads on how to proceed?

Answer: The application logic to identify the protocols and application would be fixed cost. So the first goal is to ensure pre-processing and post-processing stages lead to minimal loss. These get varied from physical NIC to virtual NIC too.

So let me explain a few pointers I follow for the best result.

1. In virtual NIC, I use memif or vhost for the best performance.
2. if I know specific IP, VLAN, MPLS, VXLAN which get filtered I prefer to use AF_XDP PMD on the virtual NIC that bifurcates the traffic.
3. In the case of physical NIC, use the NIC that supports PTYPES, RSS, QUEUE redirection.

(Physical NIC offload)

1. Using RSS, one can program RSS to spread traffic on all queues.
2. Combining queue redirection with RSS, one can specifically send the desired traffic like IPv4, IPv6, VxLAN, GRE, Geneve, GTPu to be RSS on selective queues. This allows all ARP, ND, lldp and other packets to fall onto default queue.
3. Using DPDK APi `rte_eth_dev_set_ptypes` enable rte_mbuf to carry ptype information from descriptor.
4. ensure to use vector mode (AVX2 and|or AV512) with smaller descriptor size if possible for certain NIC.

So well-tuned (BIOS and Kernel Command Line) lcores will now be able to get RX packets DMA with enough metadata. ***This will allow the extra overhead to parse each packet to reduce since selected traffic is sent to a specific queue and the PTYPE on the RSS queue helps to do an early filter***.

Then divide the development into multiple stages

- stage-1: rx packets and increments protocol counters then use rte_mbuf_free without drops
- stage-2: increment ref_cnt for the interested packet, and do tx_burst. then perform stage-2
- stage-3: run single instance of optimized application-parser and how much cycles overhead comes in and is there packet drops

if packet drops are present, it means single queue traffic needs either spread to multiple queues (more RX queues) in case of the run to completion model. Else explore the option of using `eventdev or flow distributor` with multiple lcore threads as application parsers.

Note:

- as pointed out, one can use HW FPGA lookaside or SW regex like (hyperscan) to achieve optimized application parsing.
- this will work with clear text, in case of TLS, for connection which doesn't have keys to be terminated can be bypassed by `using rte_flow to carry 32bit marker`.

Above logic is true for IDS mode. In case of `IPS` mode, sometimes requirements will be come to ensure packet ordering. So use atomic eventdev for all the 3 stages.